# How to add a suitable margin

Tags: sectioning, indentation

[image]

How can I make the second line have an indentation such that it aligns with the "If" of the first line (I want to define some kind of section s.t. always when I'm in this section I get this indentation)?

Comment: You can use  a custom `enumerate` environment, with the `enumitem` package.

Comment: section as if? Is 1-10 a section? Can you provide MWE?

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, I thought I would show every way I could think of to achieve this effect.  Interestingly, using amsthm or enumerate took too much effort.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{paracol}

\newcounter{theorem}
\renewcommand{\thetheorem}{\thesection-\arabic{theorem}}
\setcounter{section}{10}

\globalcounter{theorem}% for paracol

\begin{document} 

\begin{itemize}
\item[\stepcounter{theorem}\thetheorem] \blindtext
\end{itemize}

\hangindent=2.5em
\noindent\hbox to 2.5em{\stepcounter{theorem}\thetheorem\hfill}\blindtext

\medskip
\noindent\makebox[2.5em][l]{\stepcounter{theorem}\thetheorem}%
  \parbox[t]{\dimexpr \textwidth-2.5em}{\blindtext}% will not break across tables

\setcolumnwidth{\dimexpr 2.5em-\columnsep}%
\medskip
\begin{paracol}{2}
\parindent=0pt
\stepcounter{theorem}\thetheorem
\switchcolumn
\blindtext
\end{paracol}

\end{document}
```